# How to align list items with svg polygon?

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to create a nav bar with a svg triangle mask. My problem is I don't know how to align my triangle with the list items. With the help of a previous stackoverflow user, I was able to fork their jsfiddle and come up with the following html code:

```
<body>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <rect id='tri-bar' width="100%" height="100%"/> 
        <mask id='tri-mask'>
             <use xlink:href='#tri-bar' fill='white'/>
             <polygon transform='translate(500,0)' points='0 101, 10 90, 20 101' fill='black'/>
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <image xlink:href="http://placekitten.com/g/700/100" width="100%" height="100%" class="target" />

</svg>

<div> 
<ul>
     <li>Blah</li>
     <li>BLih</li>    
     <li>Blah</li>
     <li>BLih</li>
</ul>
</div>    
</body>
```

and the following css:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png') no-repeat 0 0 scroll;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin-top: 60px;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
}

ul li {
    float: right;
    width: 10%;
}

svg, div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 700px;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: -1;
}

.target {
    mask: url(#tri-mask);
}
```

Here is a working jsfiddle illustrating what I am trying to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/billy2020/W6vf8/

Is it possible to align the list items with the triangle? If not, is their another solution to achieve this? I would like to use the translate mechanism to animate the triangle later.

Answer (score 0):

If one or the other side is single colored then I would go for the CSS triangle trick. I've created a negative triangle too: http://codepen.io/gionkunz/pen/ihgwH